# Pandas select unique values from column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I was able to ingest a csv in jupyter notes by doing this :

```
csvData= pd.read_csv("logfile.csv")
```

My data looks like this:

```
event_timestamp ip  url 
2018-01-10 00:00 111.111.111.111 http://webpage1.com
2018-01-10 00:00 222.222.222.222 http://webpage2.com
...
..
.
```

I got a list of unique ips:

```
list_ips = csvData("[ip]")
```

What I'm trying to do is get a **unique**. Normally I would do:

```
list_ips.unique()
```

But in this case I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

(I can use list_ips.head() and it will list a few IPs but it's not a unique list)

Thanks

***EDIT***
My problem is I actually had:

```
list_ips = csvData([["ip"]])
```

So I removed 1 set of brackets so it became:

```
list_ips = csvData(["ip"])
```

Then I was able to follow Wen's example and do:

```
list_ips.unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['111.111.111.111','222.222.222.222'...]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to select the column correctly then apply `unique`

```
csvData['ip'].unique().tolist()
Out[677]: ['111.111.111.111', '222.222.222.222']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are running into this problem is because `pd.read_csv("logfile.csv").unique()` is not a valid attribute from DataFrame. What I suggest you do is since csvData comes out as a list, you can search for all ip's by `csvData['ip']` then search for unique ip's with `csvData['ip'].unique()`.